# Adjusting round-off error so as to have percentages that sum up to $100$

Tags: percentage, methodology, constraint, rounding

I have non-negative numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n$. These numbers are all percentages rounded to the nearest tenth of a percentage. Unfortunately, I don't have any of the numerators or denominators driving these percentages.

The true percentages, $t_1, \dots, t_n$, are unknown and should obviously sum up to $100$. But this is not the case for the numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n$, due to rounding error. The denominators for each of these $x_i$ are identical, and it is known that the numerators of the $x_i$ take on nonnegative-integer values.

Is there a transformation I can attempt, say $Y_k = f_k(x_k)$, so that

- $0 \leq Y_k \leq 100$ for each $k = 1, \dots, n$, and
- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k = 100$?

For purposes of computational feasibility, you may assume $n \leq 60$.

---

One possibility would be to draw random variables $(U_k)$ from a uniform distribution in $(-0.05, 0.05)$ and let $Y_k = x_k + U_k$ for each $k = 1, \dots, n$. The difficulty here lies with the constraints:

- $0 \leq Y_k \leq 100$ for each $k = 1, \dots, n$, and
- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k = 100$

---

**Edit**: Here's another possibility.

We aim to solve the optimization problem
$$\min \sum_{k=1}^{n}(y_k - x_k)^2$$
subject to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_k = 1$$
and $y_k \geq 0$ for all $k$.

I believe this is a quadratic programming problem. My background in optimization is very weak, however; and I wouldn't know how to obtain closed-form solutions for the $y_k$.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer weights the data incorrectly for the implied circumstances.  In principle, each $x_i$ is afflicted by approximately the same *expected* error, but the straight normalization weights each $x_i$ in proportion to $x_i$ itself.  Is this really what you wanted?

Comment: @whuber You make good points, and I didn't think about them when I accepted the answer.

Comment: @whuber I'll entertain other answers for a few days and may issue a bounty, but yes, I find your points are completely valid.

Comment: Are the (unknown) numerators and denominators integral?  Are all the denominators the same?

Comment: @whuber Yes to both.

Comment: @whuber with all those unknowns, I don't think there is a better solution, is there?

Comment: @Tim It depends on whether you think the answer I posted is any better ;-).

Comment: A very good related reference on this is Persi Diaconis & David Freedman (1979) On Rounding Percentages, Journal of the American Statistical Association, 74:366a, 359-364, DOI: 10.1080/01621459.1979.10482518.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can often solve this problem with a linear search.**  This post provides some theory and code.

#### Theory

Let the data be, as in the question, $x_1,\ldots, x_n.$  These began as non-negative integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ which, when expressed as proportions of the whole (the sum $N=a_1+\cdots+a_n$), are rounded versions of $z_i = a_i/N.$

*Rounding* is straightforward but a little complicated to describe.

1. When we round $z$ to $d\ge 0$ digits we are rounding the value $10^d z$ to the nearest integer and then multiplying the result by $10^{-d}.$  Thus we may focus on the process of rounding numbers $z$ to the nearest integer.  *For this post alone,* let $[z]$ designate the result of rounding to an integer.  (This is a conventional notation for discussions of rounding.)
2. The nearest integers to $z$ are its floor $\lfloor z \rfloor$ and its ceiling $\lceil z \rceil,$ for which $\lfloor z \rfloor \le z \le \lceil z \rceil.$

   - When one of these integers is closest to $z,$ it is the rounded version of $z.$  In particular, the distance between $z$ and its rounded version cannot exceed $1/2:$ $|\,z - [z]\,| \le 1/2.$
   - When $z$ lies equidistant from its floor and ceiling, it is an odd multiple of $1/2.$  Many systems -- `R` is one of them -- round to an *even* value (multiple of $2$) in those circumstances.  Thus, $[1/2] = 0,$ $[3/2] = 2,$ $[5/2] = 2,$ $[7/2]=4,$ and so on.  See, for instance, this `R` command and its output:

     ```
     > round(seq(1/2, 7/2, by=1))
     [1] 0 2 2 4
     ```

**Our objective is to infer plausible values of the $a_i$ and $N$ from the data.**  This requires us (somehow) to invert the rounding process.  To that end, it is helpful to note (from the foregoing description of rounding) that

- $|a_i/N - x_i|\,10^d = |10^d (z_i - x_i)| \le 1/2,$ whence $$x_iN - \left(\frac{10^{-d}}{2}\right)N \le a_i \le x_iN + \left(\frac{10^{-d}}{2}\right)N.\tag{*}$$
- When $|10^d a_i/N - 10^d x_i| = 1/2,$ then $10^dx_i$ is a multiple of $2.$  This refines $(*)$ by indicating which of those inequalities are strict ones.  One way to rephrase this is to consider whether $10^d x_i$ (which must be integral) is odd or even.  When it is even, it is possible for the first inequality to be equality; when it is odd, it is possible for the second inequality to be equality.

**The original question arises in circumstances where the $x_i$ do not sum to unity.**

As an example, consider $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,1,5,9).$  Here $N=1+1+5+9=16$ and, using $d=3$ digits, the fractions round to $[1/16]=0.062,$ $[5/16]=0.312,$ and $[9/16]=0.562,$ which sum to $0.998 = 1 - 2\times 10^{-d}.$  In particular, this example shows that the sum of the rounded values may differ from $1$ by as much as $n$ times the maximum rounding error of $10^{-d}/2.$

In such cases, **we would like to infer the integers $a_i$ so that we may recover more accurate versions of the $z_i$ from the data.**  Note, though, that any solution $(a_i)$ automatically gives rise to a host of solutions of the form $(ma_i)$ for any multiple $m=1,2,3,\ldots.$  There may be other solutions, too, which are not multiples of this one.  How to choose among them?  I propose the following, which arises from an application of Occam's Razor (viewing smaller denominators as "simpler"):

> To solve this problem, first specify an allowable range of values for $N,$ say from $N_0$ to $N_1,$ inclusive.  Among all possible solutions $(a_i),$ write $N=\sum a_i$ and *select the solution for which $N_0 \le N \le N_1$ and $N$ is as small as possible.*

#### An Algorithm

Let $N \ge 1$ be any candidate for the sum of the $a_i.$  When it is the correct (original) value, $(*)$ must hold for every $x_i.$  This pair of inequalities defines a (possibly empty) set $\mathcal{A}(x_i;N)$ of integers $a_i$ that satisfy them.  Ordinarily (for $N$ sufficiently small) these sets are empty or contain just one element.  It therefore is feasible and efficient to consider all tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ for which *both* $a_i\in\mathcal{A}(x_i;N)$ for all $i$ *and* $a_1+\cdots+a_n=N.$  If rounding these $a_i/N$ to $d$ digits *exactly* reproduces the data $(x_i),$ we have a solution.  Let the set of all such solutions (usually empty) be $\mathcal{S}(N).$

The algorithm is now simple to describe.  I will use pseudocode:

```
Input: Array x, integers N0, N1, and digit count d
n = length(x)
For N from N0 to N1:
    For each i from 1 to n:
        Let A[i] = A(x[i],N)
    If U (in the next step) will be too large then stop
    Let U = A[1] X A[2] X ... X A[n] {the Cartesian product}
    Let S = Empty collection
    For each array a in U:
         If sum(a) == N and round(a/N, d) == x then adjoin a to S
 Return S.
```

The output is a set (usually empty or a singleton) of plausible solutions.

#### Comments

Notice there is no test related to rounding to even values.  Omitting this test will occasionally cause the search set `U` to be too large, at some cost in computation time.  But since a solution is returned only when it checks out -- it must round *exactly* to the given data `x` -- the algorithm remains correct.  This implies this algorithm will work regardless of what form of rounding the software platform supports, *provided it is the same form used to create the data in the first place.*

When $N_0$ is not too large, most of the time the search set `U` will be very small, making the algorithm efficient.  **But note the risk:** when many of the $x_i$ have more than one candidate for $a_i,$ the size of $U$ explodes.  With $n=60$ data values and just two candidates per value, for instance, $U$ has $2^{60}$ elements.  That's why we need to check the size of $U$ before going on.  Limiting the upper search limit $N_1$ to a sufficiently small value avoids this problem.  If you cannot find any solutions, then increase $N_1$ and try again.

If the number of digits used for the original rounding was crude -- that is, it loses a lot of precision -- then this method will usually return a solution with a smaller value of $N$ than the original.  But when $d$ is reasonably large; say, when $10^{-d}N \approx 1$ (or less), then it will almost always return the original value of $N.$  The notable exceptions are when the greatest common divisor of the $a_i$ is greater than $1,$ for then there is no way to distinguish the original $a_i$ from $a_i/\operatorname{gcd}(a),$ no matter how precise the rounding might be.

#### Examples and Code

The question asks about datasets of $60$ or fewer numbers and intimates they are rounded to $\pm0.05\%,$ which is $d=3$ decimal digits.  That rounding precision would be unsuitable for numbers of three or more digits.  Let us, then, create a dataset of integers $z_i$ between $0$ and $999$ (perhaps favoring the smaller ones, since rounding them can create more relative imprecision), round them to form the $x_i,$ and see what solution(s) this algorithm produces.

The dataset processed in this example is $(a_i) = (1,2,4,5,6,\ldots, 206,238),$ whose sum is $N=4490.$  I conducted the search starting at $N_0=1$ (and limiting it, if needed, to $2\times 10^d,$ which should be more than enough).  The solution found is $N^{*}=1004,$ thereby estimating the original data as $a_i^{*} = (0,0,1,1,1,\ldots, 46,54).$  However, as promised, this solution *exactly* reproduces the rounded values of $a_i/N.$

One way to compare the original with the solution is to plot the relative errors between the *true* ratios $a_i/N$ and the estimated ratios $a_i^{*}/N^{*}.$

[image: Figure]

As one would expect, *rounding afflicts the *relative* precision of the smallest values the most.*  This is one reason we might want to work a little bit to recover the original ratios as accurately as we reasonably can.

Here's the `R` code implementing the algorithm and the data generation process to test it.

```R
#
# Determine whether a denominator `N` will yield a solution when `x` has been
# rounded to `digits` digits (base 10).
#
test <- function(N, x, digits=2, maxsols=2^10 * length(x)) {
  da <- 10^(-digits)/2 * N
  xn <- x * N
  l <- ceiling(xn - da) # Lower limits
  u <- floor(xn + da)   # Upper limits
  ranges <- lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) l[i]-1 + seq_len(u[i]-l[i]+1))
  nsols <- prod(unlist(lapply(ranges, length)))
  if (nsols <= maxsols) {
    A <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, ranges)) # Cartesian product of intervals
    A <- A[rowSums(A) == N, , drop=FALSE]        # Enforce the sum-to-N condition
    i <- apply(A, 1, function(a) all(round(a/N, digits)==x))
    A[i, , drop=FALSE]    # Return all solutions that work as rows of `A`
  } else {
    warning("Too many solutions to check (", nsols, ") for N = ", N, ".")
    matrix(0, 0, length(x))
  }
}
#
# Create a dataset.
#
digits <- 3 # E.g., 3 digits means rounding percents to 1 digit.
n <- 60                               # Dataset size
size <- 1e3                           # Maximum value of any a[i].
p <- rev(sort(runif(size)))^10 + 1e-6 # Choose smaller values preferentially
p <- p / sum(p)                       # Probabilities of 1, 2, 3, ...

set.seed(17)
a <- sort(sample.int(size, n, replace=TRUE, prob=p))-1 # (Sorting is optional)
x <- round(a / sum(a), digits)        # The data
2 * 10^digits * abs(1 - sum(x))       # Total rounding error.
#
# Find solutions.
#
N0 <- 1             # Smallest denominator to search for
N1 <- 2*10^digits   # Largest denominator ...
system.time( {
  solution <- matrix(0, 0, length(x))
  for (N in seq(N0, N1)) {
    solution <- test(N, x, digits)
    if (nrow(solution) > 0) break # Stop at smallest `N` with a solution
  }
})
if (nrow(solution) > 0) 
    rownames(solution) <- paste("Solution", seq_len(nrow(solution)))
#
# Compare the original values `a` to the solution(s).
#
(rbind(a, solution))
#
# If the original values `a` are not recovered, demonstrate that nevertheless
# they lead to the same values of `x`.
#
if(!any(sum(a) == rowSums(solution))) {
  x.star <- round(solution / sum(solution), digits)
  print(rbind(x=x, solution=x.star))
}
#
# Visually compare `a` to the solution(s), 
# adjusting for the possibility of different `N`.
#
if (nrow(solution) > 0) {
  sapply(rownames(solution), function(sname) {
    s <- solution[sname, ]
    subtitle <- if(min(a)==0) "(Errors for a=0 not computable)" else ""
    plot(a, sum(a) / sum(s) * s/a, type="n",
         ylab="a/s",
         sub=subtitle,
         main=paste("Relative errors for", sname))
    abline(h=1)
    points(a, sum(a) / sum(s) * s/a, pch=21, bg="#00000030")
  })
} else {
  warning("No solution found.  Try a larger N1 (currently ", N1, ")")
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but this assumes that the $N$ is smaller than the precision of the data. Say that the numbers are "rounded" to the second decimal point, while $N>10000$, in such case the % would be actually introducing errors, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tim As I pointed out, when one rounds too aggressively, it isn't possible to recover the original data.  I don't understand what you mean by "% ... introducing errors," though.  Regardless, this algorithm applies to any value of $N$ you might care to try--provided it's not too large. (That's the purpose of the size check.)  If you think $N$ is large, then perhaps sampling from the possible solutions would be effective: do that, then pick the one that meets any other criteria you want to impose.

Comment: Another thing you assume in here is that you know the rounding algorithm, in here IEEE 754 (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html), but if the numbers were not rounded using it (say, they were always rounded up) this would not work as intended.

Comment: @Tim I commented on that specifically, too (both in the theoretical and computational sections of this post).  But note that "rounding" in this context almost never means "always round up."  (That's a sure way to make the percents *not* sum to 100.)  The issue only concerns how to round the half-integral values.  When you're concerned about that, you can check any putative solution to see whether any half-integer percents appear: if they don't, then this wasn't an issue.

Comment: What rounding means and what people publish as "rounded" data are two different things. The numbers can be e.g. truncated rather than rounded etc. What I'm saying is that this assumes a rounding algorithm. If one can assume that, I agree, you can do a linear search. Otherwise, you are introducing additional error.

Comment: @Tim I don't disagree with your conditional statement, but I would challenge the hypothesis.  In particular *people who always round up (or round down) are using a bad procedure for reporting proportions of a whole.*  We shouldn't be concerned about being unable to fix their mistakes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and for the excellent discussion. What version of R are you using? I believe that the way the seeds work changed in recent versions, hence I'm not getting the same results, but the code works and the data and solution are similar.

Comment: I'm using 3.5.3 (64-bit architecture).  Changing how the seeds work, without offering some backwards compatibility, would be a shame, because it would make so much code irreproducible!  Do you have a reference that documents a change?

Comment: I’m just saying that such procedure may give you false sense of “restoring” the original data. How useful if would be would depend on what the data is and what you want to use if for. I can’t imagine case where I’d bother rather than just scale the data.

Comment: @whuber If I could find it, I'd link it. All I know for sure is that over the last two years, I've been teaching R for a data science class, updating R every semester, and I *know* for a fact that even though I used the same seed for one particular example, recompiling it led to slightly different results. If my memory serves, this happened sometime between Spring 2021 and Fall 2021.

Comment: @Tim One excellent use of techniques like this is to identify errors in published papers and reports.  Another is to recover some information about sample size when it's not available.  In most cases, though, your approach of just scaling the data would likely work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

$$
Y_j = \frac{x_j}{\sum_k x_k} \times 100\%
$$

If $x_k$ are fractions, they are calculated by dividing by a normalizing constant $x_j = n_j / N$ where the constant is their sum $N = \sum_k n_k$, so if you had the raw fractions (or percentages, they differ only by the $\times 100$ constant), it will hold that

$$
\frac{x_j}{\sum_k x_k} = \frac{n_j / N}{\sum_k n_k / N} = \frac{n_j}{N \sum_k n_k / N} = \frac{n_j}{\sum_k n_k}
$$

Of course, this does not do anything to correct the rounding errors, but to do so, you would need to know more on how they were rounded since there is more than one rounding convention.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k = c
$$
Divide both sides by $c$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x_k}{c}= 1
$$
Multiply both sides by 100
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{c} \cdot 100\right)= 100
$$